# Wordpress if query always returning true

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I've been using this same piece of code for several years and only in the past few weeks has it started playing up. It now shows the contents whether or not 'blog_posts' is true – can anyone tell me why this is and how I can go about fixing it?

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'blog_posts', true) ) : ?>
```

Many thanks

Comment: What's the output of get_post_meta in this case? Sounds like it's returning data, or possibly an empty object

Comment: If there is content in the 'blog_post' field then it will always be true, won't it?

Comment: What does `var_dump( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'blog_posts', true ) );` tell you?  Also: have you added any new plugins or changed theme in the 'past few weeks'?

Comment: @PatJ That gives me `array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }`. To explain a bit more fully, 'blog_posts' is a related field on the back end of the site so this should be pulling the relevant links on to the page. I've not made any changes to the site recently or added any new plugins, which is why I'm a bit stumped by the sudden change.

Comment: To complicate things further, I've just noticed that this is only happen on certain entries and not all, which would suggest it's not a problem with the code itself?

Comment: That's really odd. When `single` is set to `true`, you shouldn't be getting an array back at all. What version of WP are you running?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Codex page for `get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

> If there is nothing to return the function will return an empty array unless $single has been set to true, in which case an empty string is returned.

An empty string or empty array is **not the same** as `boolean false`.  Change your code to this:

```
<?php if( ! empty( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'blog_posts', true ) ) ) : ?>
```

and it should work as expected.

[`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) will return `boolean true` on an empty array or an empty string, so it'll work whether the `single` parameter on `get_post_meta()` is `true` or `false`.

**Edited**

I was wrong about the empty string not being the same as `boolean false`. From your comment, I see that you're getting `array( '' )` back (as opposed to `array()` or `''`) -- even though you've set the `single` parameter to `true`, which *should* return only a string.

To get this working, you can do this:

```
<?php if ( array( '' ) != get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'blog_posts', true ) ) : ?>
```

But it's still rather strange that WordPress would return an `array` even though you've specifically told it *not* to.

Comment: An empty array or an empty string evaluates to boolean false in PHP.